# Set different code for order details template in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I'm developing a theme for woocommerce website. My problem is that to show order details on my account and thank you page, woocommerce only has the following template file:

`/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php`

How to create two different template files for thank you page and my account page to show order details.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create 2 different files (which it will make it complicated).

Instead use [Woocommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-11) in your template (or in side the related hooks), like:

```
if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) 
{
    // Your code for thank you page
}
elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) 
{
    // Your code for My account > View order
}
```

This will be much more better and simpler